# Change the exit code in cash of error message

Tags: bash

AWS cli returns this error in case the stack already exists and no update must be executed.

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: No updates are to be performed.
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have an exit code equal to 0 ONLY in the case that I have that message and leave unchanged the behaviour of the command.

this is my attempt:

```
command 2>&1 | grep "No updates are to be performed."
```

but it doesn't fully work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to stop the command? Or does it finish itself?

Comment: @123 the point is that in case of that message the exit code is 255 so I want to have exit code 0 in order to not make fail the script

Comment: It should exit 0 if grep matches?

Comment: The text you quote is "No updates are to be performed." your grep looks for "No updates to be performed.". Is the difference relevant?

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry typo

Comment: @123 what I'm trying to achieve generally is to do a way that command doesn't fail (so have exit code equals to 0) when No updates are to be performed.

Comment: You want a 0 exit in case the message occurs. Do you want a non-0 exit if the message does NOT occur?

Comment: yes exit 0 if the message occures. If the message does NOT occur leave the behaviour unchanged which mean report the original exit code

Comment: Maybe I found something

`command 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | grep -q "No updates are to be performed."`

Comment: The point of the above command is that in the case the command really works then it will fails instead I should mantain the command behaviour unchanged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
command 2>&1 | tee command.output

if ! grep -q "No updates are to be performed." command.output; then
   exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
fi

exit 0
```

This will not fail when the message is equal to "No updates are to be performed." but it will exit with reporting the status code of the command

Please advice more elegant way